# Unexpected error while trying to connect to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
Your mobile device has encountered an unexpected error(0xE800002E)
Try disconnecting and powering off the device;then power the device on and reconnect it.
```

I received these message so many times. How can I fix it?

Comment: Not even remotely programming related.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions, you might have better luck on an apple support forum.

Comment: This message comes up regularly while doing iPhone development. I would also like to hear if there's anything I can do to at least reduce the incidence of the error, even if it just requires a quick reboot of the phone.

Comment: I think developers see this non-development problem more often than other users and I have seen it from Xcode so I think it _is_ (possibly tangentially) programming related.

Comment: Did you try doing what the error message recommends that you do? Did that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can see this error when you connect in XCode, it is not actually an Xcode defect.

See [this thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1632644&tstart=0) at Apple's discussion boards. You basically need to reset you phone. I'm not sure but  Ithink there may be a link between seeing this error and using your phone for development but I have no concrete evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I plug my device in and its set to automatically run iPhoto - then you must let iPhoto load and let it try to sync photos before you quit it. Then you should be able to use XCode to load an application on to your phone.

If you do get the error - unplug the device, turn it off and then back on, and that usually clears up the problem